# Learning parameters with gradient descent

Tags: python, regression

I just started a ML course and I'm trying to run gradient descent in python. The below functions work fine, but as I move on to the bigger chunk where I do the actual learning, I just can't get the expected output and learn the right parameters, as you can tell from this decision boundary I plotted afterwards. And I'm trying to figure out why.

[plotting the decision boundary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8pcS.png)

```
def sigmoid(z):
sigma = 1/(1+np.exp(-z))
return sigma

def compute_cost(X, y, w, b):
    y_hat = sigmoid((X * np.expand_dims(w, axis=0)).sum(axis=1) + b)
    total_cost =  (-y * np.log(y_hat) - (1-y) * np.log(1-y_hat)).mean()
    return total_cost

def compute_gradient(X, y, w, b): 
    z = w * X + b
    yhat = sigmoid(z)
    
    y1 = np.expand_dims(y, axis=1)
    error = yhat - y1

    db = error.mean()
    dw_j1 = (X * error)
    dw_j = np.mean(dw_j1,axis=0)

    return dw_j, db
```

Before building this gradient descent function, I tested all the above with my training data & they all work and output the correct numbers. Really appreciate it if you can spot my mistakes.

**Learning parameters with gradient descent**

```
def gradient_descent(X, y, w, b, alpha, num_iters): 
    m = len(X)
    
    J_history = []
    wb_history = []
    
    for i in range(num_iters):
      cost = compute_cost(X, y, w, b)
      dw_j, db = compute_gradient(X, y, w, b)   

      w = w - alpha * dw_j               
      b = b - alpha * db 

      wb_history.append((w,b))
      J_history.append(cost)

    if i % math.ceil(num_iters/10) == 0 or i == (num_iters-1):
            print(f"Iteration {i:4}: Cost {float(J_history[-1]):8.2f}")
  
    return w, b, J_history, wb_history



np.random.seed(1)
initial_w = 0.01 * (np.random.rand(2) - 0.5)
initial_b = -8

iterations = 10000
alpha = 0.001

w, b, J_history, _ = gradient_descent(X_train ,y_train, initial_w, initial_b, alpha, iterations)
```

Comment: Haven't looked in detail but at first glance, shouldn't there be a derivative of your activation function in the gradient calculation somewhere? I.e. dy/dz. My advice is, write out your equations first and post them so we can see whether there is a mistake in your equations or in your implementation of them.

Comment: Suggest checking out one of the many helpful articles like this one: [Gradient Descent: Show Me the Math!](https://towardsdatascience.com/gradient-descent-show-me-the-math-7ba7d1caef09)